# Best Practices for dealing with "Not Found" responses in WCF Services

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf

I have a Silverlight application that communicates to a Silverlight-enabled WCF service, both of which are under my control as a developer.

What are some of the best practices for handling exceptions that may occur in the WCF Service.

If you simply try to throw an exception in your WCF service, the exception information does not make it back to the Silverlight client. Instead, the Silverlight client receives a generic (and misleading) "Not Found" exception.

My service methods often return specific class objects. I have thought of a few approaches, but would love to get alternatives.

1. Add Exception type properties to your custom class objects and check properties of returned value.
2. Create a generic wrapper class that all methods return, that have transaction details (and exception details), as well as an attached return value object that can be any object type.
3. I did read something about modifying the WCF service to return detailed error information in the event of an exception (versus the unhelpful "not found"), but the article was incomplete and so I am still not sure that would work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight 4.0 does support the notion of Fault Contracts, but in order for exception details to be accessible in your client fault messages need to be returned with a HTTP 200 response. The following gives all the details (take a look under the heading **Configuring WCF SOAP Faults for Use with Silverlight Clients**):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556(VS.95).aspx

In terms of best practices take a look at the web service architecture guidelines of the Web Service Software factory:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699426.aspx

Specifically, the topic on Exception Handling:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699460.aspx

These guidances are all provided from the POV of WCF implementations...

Answer (score 0):

Check out that link to trap the "Not Found" error :

http://blogs.runatserver.com/lppinson/post/2010/04/15/Debugging-WCF-Web-Services.aspx